# Do hashes resemble a format language when decrypting

Tags: encryption

I am fairly new to cryptography, but I have come across this :

```
ea706916-4d0a-460d-9778-4d1a7195b229
```

which looks like a familiar format. It's original value is tjotol.

Would anyone know what format the above code is in? I know that if it has hashes it can be a giveaway. Base64? HTML? Something else?

Comment: [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) has absolutely nothing to do with encryption or hashing, it's a tag language for web pages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), it may be [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) with dashes in-between. However, remember that a hash is a one-way function (ie. it's not reversible), while a cryptographic function is two-way (you can encrypt and decrypt it). Hence, it's not correct to speak about "hash decrypting". I don't know what you mean by "format language", would you care to elaborate on that?

A quick google search took me to [this article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) that seems to be well written an covering many issues regarding your concern related to hashes being a "giveaway".

Note: Base64 is hardly an encryption algorithm, it is indeed just an encoding/representation format.

Answer (score 1):

This have the format of a Globally unique identifier (**GUID**). Take a look here: [Globally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)